# How can I use multiple Laravel job tables?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-queue

I have two Laravel apps sharing a database and `jobs` table. The crontab entries below are responsible for running the `queue:work` commands:

```
# App2 - path to app 2 - App with Account model and accounts table
* * * * * uname cd /app2/ && php artisan schedule:run

# App1 - path to app 1 - App with User Model and users table
* * * * * uname cd /app1/ && php artisan schedule:run
```

Here is my issue, when a user in app1 tries to recover his password by submitting his email, the accounts table is rather queried instead of the users table giving me a wrong name in the email that is sent to the user. What can be the problem?

My queue driver is database, this is the email code:

```php
public function emailResetLink(CanResetPasswordContract $user, 
                               string $token, Closure $callback = null)
{
    $view = $this->emailView;

    return $this->mailer->queue(
        $view,
        compact('token', 'user'),
        function ($m) use ($user, $token, $callback) {
            $m->to($user->getEmailForPasswordReset());

            if (! is_null($callback)) {
                call_user_func($callback, $m, $user, $token);
            }
        }
    );
}
```

This is in the email view:

```html
Dear {{ $user->name }},<br/><br/> <!-- I get the wrong name --> 
{{ trans('passwords.password_email_text_one') }}
```

Answer (score 4):

Make a few connections inside `config/queue.php`, setting a different table name on each:

```php
<?php
return [
    'connections' => [
        'accountConnection' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'accounts',
            'queue' => 'accountqueue',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
        'userConnection' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'users',
            'queue' => 'userqueue',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],
];
```

Then specify a separate connection when adding a job,

```php
Queue::connection("accountConnection")->push($job);
// or
$job->dispatch()->onConnection("accountConnection");
```

And after, use

```bash
php artisan queue:work accountConnection
```

To run the specific queue connection.

To create a migration for the queue table, run

```bash
php artisan queue:table
```

Once migration is created you can copy it, rename the table, and make sure table names are set correctly in `config/queue.php`.

Comment: Thank you so much @lifekent. I am trying this out to see what I get. You're awesome.

Comment: @lifekent can you please update your reply with the command(s) to create both the Jobs tables?